# amCharts, cannot disable animation in word cloud

Tags: amcharts, word-cloud, amcharts5

I am using amCharts v.5 to make [word clouds](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/word-cloud/), but I can't find a way to reduce nor to remove animation.

Animation is shown independently from the implementation of [Animated](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/) theme.

I read documentation and it seems strange that word clouds' animation isn't manageable. I wonder if I'm missing something.